# "ProtectedData.Unprotect(password, entropy)" always returning null in UWP

Tags: windows-store-apps, uwp, windows, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-universal

I have windows phone8.0 (silverlight) App which i want to upgrade to UWP. in Windows Phone 8.0 App i was using "ProtectedData.Protect(passwordData, entropy)"(mscorlib.extensions.dll, v2.0.5.0) to protect some specific string. but when i am trying to use "ProtectedData.UnProtect(passwordData, entropy)" or "ProtectedData.Unprotect(passwordData, entropy)" in UWP Application. i am always getting null  after execution of ProtectedData.UnProtect(passwordData, entropy) line of code.

please suggest me if am missing anything ?

Thanks,

Comment: I think you can't use mscorlib.extensions.dll- you have to support SQLCiper of Transparent Data Encryption with Azure SQL Database - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn948096.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 
let me know if that support your question - if yes, I'll add an answer

Comment: Hey DeJaVo, thanks for replying. first of all sorry to misleading description of problem. the real problem is i was using  ProtectedData.Protect(passwordData, entropy) to protect certain string. if i am using "ProtectedData.Unprotect(passwordData, entropy)" to Unprotect the same string in UWP Application. it is always returning null.

Comment: What's the platform you are using? The [ProtectedData.Protect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh133538(v=vs.95).aspx) and [ProtectedData.Unprotect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh133478(v=vs.95).aspx) method are for Windows Phone Silverlight, they can't be used in UWP directly. You can use [DataProtectionProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.dataprotection.dataprotectionprovider.aspx) class instead.

Comment: Hi Zuo, what if i have an windows phone silverlight app on the store already and in that app i have used ProtectData.Protect(...) with entroy. if i want to replace the existing silverlight app with UWP app on the store. so in UWP how can i use entropy in DataProtectionProvider class ? i dont see any option to use entropy there .

Answer (score 2):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380882(v=vs.85).aspx#
we can follow this link to unprotect the data. there we have to import "crypt32.dll".

example code is here.
http://www.icodeguru.com/dotnet/ms-visual-csharp-dot-net-unleashed/0672326760/ch35lev1sec4.html